# Transferring Audiobooks to another Macintosh

Tags: macos, iphone, books

I don’t think anyone would accuse Apple of making things too obvious.

I have an iMac which I am retiring. My new machine is a Mac Mini.

I have a number of audiobooks which come from a third party. Basically from CDs. Until recently I could access them on my iPhone in the Books app.

Since updating to a new iPhone about a week ago, and my Mac a few days ago, I appear to have lost track of my audio books. The old iMac still sees them, but the new Mini doesn’t, and neither does the iPhone.

Audio books from the book store do appear on the new iPhone and Mac, but not the additional books.

How do I get the additional books to transfer?